# Why isn't a linearly dependent set in $\mathbb R^n$ a spanning set in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Aren't there some cases where they do in fact span $\mathbb R^n$?

E.g: the set of vectors $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2)$ in $\mathbb R^3$

Clearly the first three vectors form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ and span all of $\mathbb R^3$. The vector $(0,0,2)$ can also be used in different scalar combinations with other vectors in the set to reach any point $\mathbb R^3$ so why would adding it to the set suddenly make the set not span $\mathbb R^3$?

Might it be due to some formal definition of a spanning set of a subspace being the basis of that subspace or something alike?

Comment: Spanning, yes, but not *minimally* spanning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0,0,1),(0,0,2)\}$ is not linearly independent and they do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If you already have a set that span $\mathbb{R}^n$, adding more vectors do not change the property that it span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Therefore a linearly dependent set can in fact span $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

That set of vectors does span $\mathbb{R}^3$ but it is not linear independent.

So if some set is not linear independant it can still span some space.

If you add any vector to base set of space $V$ it still spans $V$.